# I am trying to remove the last item of each list in a list of lists

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I have a data structure which is a list of lists. I want to remove the last item of each list, preferably using a filter. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: `map` `f` over your list of list, where `f` is a function that removes the last element of a list.

Comment: This is typically not a use-case for a filter: this is a "mapping" (since you apply a function on each item of the list). I think instead of first tackling the list of lists problem, it might be better to first make an attempt on removing the last item of a *single* list.

Comment: what should happen if the sublist is empty?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example show how to do it:

```
map (\xs->if null xs then xs else init xs) [[], [1..3], [4..6]]
```

and the result is:

```
[[],[1,2],[4,5]]
```

Note that it need to check each list in list whether is empty before remove the last item of the list, since `init` cannot apply to empty list.

Comment: The usual idiom for dropping a given number of elements from the end of a list, automatically handling empty lists, is `zipWith const xs (drop n xs)` (`n` being 1 here), e.g. `map (\xs -> zipWith const xs (drop 1 xs))`. This can also be written point-free rather conveniently as `map (zipWith const <*> drop 1)`, but I appreciate not everyone finds the `(->)` applicative pleasant to read.

Comment: @JonPurdy I am not sure which way is better, both are O(n) and able to handle infinite list. I choose `if null xs...` version since it is easy to understand for newbie of Haskell.

Comment: Yeah, I think your method is a more appropriate answer to this particular question. I just wanted to mention the alternative because it’s an idiom that’s not necessarily intuitive at first, but someone may encounter it in the wild.

Comment: @JonPurdy Yes, you are right and your supplementary explanation in comment is useful, so I voted it up. In practical, your method is preferred and general to remove arbirary  number of elements at the end of the list, but  the method in my answer is not suitable to remove more than 1 element from the end of the list.